# How to combine dictionary lookup with When condition and with_items

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need help with the correct syntax of `Pre-reboot task for node servers` task below.

I have multiple EC2 instances with **tag:Name** equal to **webapp1, webapp2, webapp3 and intranet1, intranet2.**
I am trying to create a generic task to stop node services on each server before I patch and reboot each one of them.

In the task below, I am basically trying to implement a lookup of dictionary to get `app_name` and `app_folder` for each server (and pass it to `stop-node-services.yml`) when the **tag:Name** of **EC2 instance** matches the `nodeapps` **key** name for e.g. `webapp` or `intranet` (from vars).

**Note:** the variable `name_tag` in the `when` condition below contains the Instance's tag:Name which comes for `ec2_instance_facts` module further up in the playbook:
`name_tag: "{{ ec2_facts.instances[0].tags.Name }}"`

````
        nodeapps:
          webapp:
            app_name: webapp55
            app_folder: applications/webapp123
          intranet:
            app_name: intranet66
            app_folder: applications/intranet234


# Pre-reboot task for node servers
- include: stop-node-services.yml 
  with_items:
    - { name : "{{ item.value.app_name }}", folder : "{{ item.value.app_folder }}" }
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', nodeapps) }}"
  when:  
    - name_tag is regex("{{ item.key }}\d")


### This is whats in the stop-node-services.yml ###
- name: restart service 
  become: true
  become_user: ubuntu
  shell: sudo sv stop . 
  args:
    chdir: /var/hubdoc/{{ item.folder }}

- debug:
    msg: "The '{{ item.name }}' on {{ inventory_hostname }} - service stopped"```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax worked for me. Posting answer here for others to benefit:

```
- include: stop-node-services.yml name={{ item.value.app_name }} folder={{ item.value.app_folder }}
  when: tags is regex("{{ item.key }}\d")
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', nodeapps) }}"


### This is whats in the stop-node-services.yml ###
- name: stop service 
  become: true
  become_user: ubuntu
  shell: sudo sv stop . 
  args:
    chdir: /var/hubdoc/{{ folder }}

- debug:
    msg: "The '{{ name }}' on {{ inventory_hostname }} - service stopped"
```

Comment: You cannot combine with_items and loop as `with_items` is `loop` under the hood.